# ant design table with dynamic children columns

Tags: reactjs, jsx, antd

I'm using ant's table and trying to setup dynamic columns.

What I need is a table that shows a list of users with their performance for each of the classes as in the example below.

[image]

Details: I have a grouped column `Performance` that can have different sub-columns (current example shows columns `science` and `physics`). I'm calling renderContent() which sets up an object that has property `children`. I found this "solution" from ant's example [here](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-colspan-rowspan). The problem is that ant's example outputs children prop type string, while my function outputs prop type array. Which results in the error.

Here is a link to sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/ecstatic-cookies-4nvci?fontsize=14

*Note: if you uncomment children array in columns [line 46-59], you will see what my expected result should be.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The render method shouldn't return the object with children array.  To use the `render` method, you would have to return a valid React component (or simply HTML tag ---like span).

However in your case, I prefer we extract subjects before passing it into the table and then generate children array dynamically. Something like below:

```
const renderContent = (value, row, index) => {
  return setupPerformance(value)

};

const setupPerformance = performance => {
  return performance.map(p => {
    const { id, title, percentage } = p;
    return <span>{percentage}%</span>
  });
};
const data = [
  {
    key: 0,
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Smith",
    performance: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "science",
        percentage: 75
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "physics",
        percentage: 36
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    key: 1,
    firstName: "Ann",
    lastName: "Smith",
    performance: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "science",
        percentage: 68,
        timeSpent: 50,
        completionDate: "2019-02-07"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "physics",
        percentage: 100
      }
    ]
  }
];
let subjects = data[0].performance
const columns = [
  {
    title: "Full Name",
    children: [
      {
        title: "firstName",
        dataIndex: "firstName",
        key: "firstName"
      },
      {
        title: "lastName",
        dataIndex: "lastName",
        key: "lastName"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "Performance",
    dataIndex: "performance",
    children: 
    subjects.map(e => {
       return {
          title: e.title,
          dataIndex: "performance["+(e.id-1)+"].percentage",
          key: "key-"+e.id,
          render: value => <span>{value}%</span>
        }
    })

  }
];
```

Comment: this is a bit of a different approach than the one I was thinking about but it works so thank you!

Comment: If you mind, please update these answer, because using dataIndex: "performance["+(e.id-1)+"].percentage", does not work anymore. You can checkout on the sandbox link in the question section.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the solution in answer from [Mobeen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57209074/5411817) does not work anymore, I have tried to solve this.

I have extended the render method for the children columns of `performance` column:

```
...
  {
    title: "Performance",
    dataIndex: "performance",
    children: subjects.map((assessment) => {
      const { title, id } = assessment;
      return {
        title,
        dataIndex: "performance",
        key: id,
        render: (values) =>
          values.map((value, index) => {
            let ret;
            if (index === id - 1) ret = values[index].percentage + "%";
            return ret;
          })
      };
    })
  }
...
```

It returns only the `percentage` value of the subject with the corresponding `id`.

It is not very clean, but it works.

Check the solution in sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-lake-7n6zgj